# Compress PDF files in R to make it faster to create corpus

Tags: r, pdf, corpus

I am doing a structural topic model of a large number of documents. The corpus is created from over 2500 pdf-files, and naturally, it takes a very long time to process these. However, I can see, that if I exclude some of the very large files (some are up to 100 MBs, although most are in the 2-5 mb range), it is so much faster.

Therefore, I am on the lookout for a way to programmatically compress the files in R. For example, could one delete images in PDFs?

Could anyone perhaps point me in the correct direction? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are these files large? Because of a massive amount of text or because they include pictures and multi-media files? I do not think you want compression because your goal is processing the content of these files. Your question "could one delete images in PDFs"  is a good one. You might want to focus on this.

Answer (score 1):

You could extract only the text from those PDF, save them to file and use them for further processing

```
library(pdftools)
pdf_files <- list.files("PDF_FOLDER", "(?i)\\.pdf$")
for(pdf in pdf_files) {
  txt <- pdf_text(pdf)
  writeLines(txt, "FILENAME BUILT FROM pdf")
}
```